# How to connect a button click to a customcontrol in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Simple newbie question.

I have a button that currently executes "insert" code in the viewmodel:

```
 <Button Content="Insert" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Height="75" 
               Command="{Binding Insert}" />
```

In the same user control, I have a customcontrol, CustomInkCanvas, defined as:

```
<wc:CustomInkCanvas x:Name="myInkCanvas"
                    Vocabulary="{Binding Vocabulary, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                    Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    WordPad="{Binding WordPad, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    CloseCharacterPads ="{Binding CloseCharacterPads}"
                    EditWord ="{Binding EditWord}"                
                />
```

What I would like to do is add something along the lines of:

```
       FormatText = {Binding ??? ElementName=Insert ???}
```

to the customcontrol xaml such that clicking on the Button will send a message to the customcontrol to reformat itself. Also this reformatting will need to be done BEFORE the "insert" method of the viewmodel which the button is connected to.   Just to be clear, I need the click on the button to first tell the custominkcanvas to reformat before doing the activity in the viewmodel.

Can this be done in through the XAML and if so how?

Thanks in advance for any help with this. (If I have a strong point, XAML is not it!)

Comment: Can you create a dependency property on the CustomInkCanvas and bind it to a property on the viewmodel?

Comment: @Taekahn  yes. Assuming "FormatText" is the dependency property, how would the "{Binding..." expression be written in Xaml to capture the button click event? Thanks.

Comment: As @dellywheel demonstrated below, you simply bind to the property and set its text at the start of the command function. The one thing i would add would be that unless you want to filter on the same string twice, either check if the value being set in the setter is equal to the current value, or make sure to check that in the custom control before doing the filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with 2 properties one on the view model and one on the custom control

CustomInkCanvas.cs

```
public string FormatText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FormatTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FormatTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FormatText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormatTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FormatText", typeof(string),
        typeof(CustomInkCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

In your ViewModel (class will need to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**)

```
private string _updatedText = string.Empty;

    public string UpdatedText
    {
        get { return _updatedText ; }
        set
        {
            _updatedText = value;
            OnPropertyChnaged("UpdatedText");
        }
    }
```

then on your custom control

```
<wc:CustomInkCanvas x:Name="myInkCanvas"
  FormatText={Binding Path="UpdatedText"} />
```

in your command **Insert**

```
this.UpdatedText = "your text";
//your insert code
```

Comment: anyway to bind the click event of the button directly to the customcontrol in the XAML? Thanks.